# What is a Makefile? And how is it different from a Gruntfile or npm run?

Tags: makefile, gruntjs, npm

Recently, while getting acquainted with the [Mocha javascript testing framework](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#best-practices), I came across this section that I didn't understand:

> Makefiles
>
> Be kind and don't make developers hunt around in your docs to figure
>   out how to run the tests, add a make test target to your Makefile:

```
test:
    ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --reporter list

.PHONY: test
```

Which is hardly descriptive, and not very helpful if you don't know what a makefile is.

So, What is a Makefile? And how is it different from a Gruntfile or using `npm run`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Makefile

A Makefile (usually with no file extension) is a configuration file used by the Unix `make` tool.

Quoted from one of the [best introductions I have found on Make](http://shapeshed.com/making-the-case-for-make/) that I highly recommend you read if you are interested in knowing more about make specifically, and task-runners in general.

> Make is the original UNIX build tool. It existed a long time before
>   gulp, or grunt. Loved by some, loathed by others it is at least worth
>   being aware of how make works, what the strengths are and where it
>   falls short.
>
> Make is available on UNIX-like systems. That means OSX, BSD and Linux.
>   It exposes any system command meaning that you can run system commands
>   and execute arbitrary scripts. There is no doubt that tools like gulp
>   and grunt are inpsired by or at least a reaction to make.
>
> To use make you create a Makefile and then run make [what to run] from
>   the terminal.

## Gruntfile.js

A Gruntfile.js is a javascript configuration file used by the [Grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/) tool.

The newer node.js version of make, if you will, is Grunt.js which is cross-platform (works on Windows) and written in Javascript.  Both can do similar things like concatenate files, minify css, run tests, etc. and there is a lot of information on the web about Grunt.

## 'npm run'

Another option that some developers prefer to use is npm itself, using the `npm run` command as described in this [informative post on how to use npm run for running tasks](http://substack.net/task_automation_with_npm_run):

> There are some fancy tools [Grunt] for doing build automation on javascript
>   projects that I've never felt the appeal of because the lesser-known
>   npm run command has been perfectly adequate for everything I've needed
>   to do while maintaining a very tiny configuration footprint.
>
> If you haven't seen it before, npm looks at a field called scripts in
>   the package.json of a project in order to make things like npm test
>   from the scripts.test field and npm start from the scripts.start field
>   work.
>
> npm test and npm start are just shortcuts for npm run test and npm run
>   start and you can use npm run to run whichever entries in the scripts
>   field you want!

## Other good introductory resources:

- [Introduction to grunt.js and npm scripts, and choosing between the
  two.](http://superbigtree.tumblr.com/post/59519017137/introduction-to-grunt-js-and-npm-scripts-and-choosing)
- [Cross platform JavaScript.](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/cross-platform-javascript/)
- [Package Managers: An Introductory Guide For The Uninitiated Front-End
  Developer.](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1190/package-managers-an-introductory-guide-for-the-uninitiated-front-end-developer#front_end_developers)

Comment: The GNU implementation of `make` runs not only on UNIX/POSIX systems, but also Windows (in various forms including DOS, native MSVC, MinGW, and Cygwin), OS/2, VMS, and even AmigaOS.  FWIW.